# Different margins for on-screen pdf and for printed pdf

Tags: margins, printing

Is it possible to have different margins for printing from those shown on screen? I'm writing my thesis and for the paper version I would like a larger inner margin to allow space for the binding, but when viewed on screen I'd like the text to be centred (so left margin = right margin).

Here's a MWE (with margins for printing and binding):

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[bottom=3cm,top=3cm,outer=3cm,inner=4cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}

\end{document}
```

So for printing I would like

```
\usepackage[bottom=3cm,top=3cm,outer=3cm,inner=4cm]{geometry}
```

but for on-screen viewing I would like

```
\usepackage[bottom=3cm,top=3cm,outer=3.5cm,inner=3.5cm]{geometry}
```

Obviously I could just make two different pdf files, one for printing and one for on-screen viewing, but I think it would be pretty cool if this could be done with just one file (much like the `ocgcolorlinks` option for the `hyperref` package disables colours for printing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your preamble

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ifdefined\screenview
screenview % set margins for screen
\else
PDF % set margins for PDF
\fi

\end{document}
```

On command line

```
pdflatex "\def\screenview{} \input{whatever.tex}"
```

Note: I've no idea what the extra braces in `\screenview{}` are for, but they do seem to be necessary.

Comment: I've added your suggestion to the preamble (ended with `\fi`, right?). The document compiles with the regular command `pdflatex whatever.tex`, giving the non-centred margins for printing, but when I try the command you suggested, the terminal starts its thing but then jams up after loading the Babel languages. This may well have something to do with the Linux on my machine though (it's a university network machine and I have no admin rights), rather than with the TeX code. Is there a alternative solution?

Comment: @DanielWolf See my updated answer for a solution I don't understand.

Comment: Without the curly brackets, you are trying to define `\screenview` as ` \input{whatever.tex}` which means every time you use `\screenview` it must be used as `\screenview \input` and it will then produce the text `whatever.tex`. I think. Certainly it won't do what you want, even if I'm wrong about what it does which you don't want.

Comment: @cfr Once you explained it it makes perfect sense thanks.

Comment: @EthanBolker It now compiles okay. However, while it appears centred on screen, it also prints centred. Just to clarify, this is my preamble:

`\ifdefined\screenview
\usepackage[bottom=3cm,top=3cm,outer=3.5cm,inner=3.5cm,headheight=16pt,heightrounded=true]{geometry}
\else
\usepackage[bottom=3cm,top=3cm,outer=3cm,inner=4cm,headheight=16pt,heightrounded=true]{geometry}
\fi`

Comment: @DanielWolf That's really a different question, about how the `geometry` package works, perhaps how it interacts with the `book` class and the conditional margin settings. I suggest you ask a new question, with a complete MWE - just a little text instead of including chapters. Post scaled down images of the two kinds of pages. That might get more attention than editing this one, or carrying on the discussion in comments.

Comment: @EthanBolker [Done](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317520/conditional-margins-for-printing). Thanks for your help.