# Conditional margins for printing

Tags: margins, printing

This is a follow up question to [Different margins for on-screen pdf and for printed pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317381/different-margins-for-on-screen-pdf-and-for-printed-pdf).

I would like different margins for on-screen viewing and for paper. So, if someone views the pdf on a screen, they see centred text, but if they print it out, the margins have been adjusted to allow space for binding. See the images at the bottom for what I mean: The left one is for on-screen viewing and the right one is for paper (I've made the difference in margin sizes very large in order to make it more obvious).

Based on an answer to the aforementioned question by @EthanBolker, here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt,openright]{book}

\ifdefined\screenview
\usepackage[bottom=3cm,top=3cm,outer=3.5cm,inner=3.5cm]{geometry} % Margins for on-screen viewing
\else
\usepackage[bottom=3cm,top=3cm,outer=1cm,inner=6cm]{geometry} % Margins for printing
\fi

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

One then compiles this with the following command:

```
pdflatex "\def\screenview{} \input{filename.tex}"
```

Alas this doesn't work though: both the one-screen and printed versions are centred. It would seem that the `geometry` package doesn't work with conditionals like that. Any ideas?

[image: Margins for on-screen viewing]
[image]

Comment: doesn't this just select one of the options? Have you tried leaving out the option, and only using the command `pdflatex \input{filename.tex}" I don't think this will do anything to accomplish your goal of having only one pdf which would change it´s own margins if it is printed or viewed on a computer.

Comment: You may have misunderstood the answer you quoted. The idea is that `pdflatex filename.tex` will build the print version and `pdflatex "\def\screenview{} \input{filename.tex}` will build the screen version. In the end you get two different PDFs optimized for two different purposes.

Comment: What you want to do is technically possible within the PDF specification. What you really need to do is to build the document in TWO layers with different margin off sets and make use of the [OCG properties](http://www.planetpdf.com/developer/article.asp?ContentID=focus_on_pdf_layers_ocg_) to set one as default visible and the other as default for print. I don't think there is a LaTeX package for automating this yet. One of the big problems being that if you change the various layout options, the screen and print versions need not have the same length!

Comment: ... which is obviously a problem if you are using the layers, since the page count of the document is fixed. I don't think PDF was/is designed with something similar to the [CSS3 @media](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) rule in mind.

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, I definitely misunderstood the answer I quoted! The compiling behaviour makes sense now.

I'm already using OCG to disable colour for printing and I thought something similar for margins might be possible within LaTeX (assuming, as you mention, that the total sum of the left and right margins remains constant so that the pagination isn't changed).

It sounds like achieving what I want would require considerable effort and time, the latter being in short supply for me right now, as my thesis deadline is fast approaching. Many thanks nonetheless though!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was based on a misunderstanding.